# Is Nodejs actually asynchronus?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I saw this post: https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/manage-async-nodejs-callback-example-code, and after running the codes I confirm that nodejs is asynchronus.
However I created 2 js files to test asynchronus feature of nodejs again.

File 1: **callback_example.js**

```
exports.countless = function(callback){
    var date = new Date();
    console.log("*" + date.getSeconds());
    var x = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 1000000000; i++){
        x++;
    }
    callback(x);
    date = new Date();
    console.log("**" + date.getSeconds());
}

exports.check = function(callback){
    var date = new Date();
    console.log(date.getSeconds());
    callback(123);
    date = new Date();
    console.log(date.getSeconds());
}
```

File 2: **call.js**

```
var call = require('./callback_example');

call.countless(function(x){
    console.log(x);
});

call.check(function(x){
    console.log(x);
});
```

And when I execute call.js in terminal as `node call`, I saw that **after countless() finished, then check() run**. It means that **nodejs is synchronus?** Why? Can anyone help me answer that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Painting too broad a statement that *"nodejs is asynchronous"* but it certainly can use asynchronous operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node.js uses the V8 Javascript engine and it executes lines of Javascript synchronous one after the other.  If you write sequential coding statements such as in both your `countless` and `check` methods in your question, then those are executed synchronously just like in pretty much any other programming language.

Here's part of the node.js description from https://nodejs.org/en/.

> Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it
>   lightweight and efficient.

This, I think, describes it better than just saying node.js is asynchronous as it described better what it actually does.

Only real asynchronous operations that make use of some outside interface such as networking are actually non-blocking in node.js.  In that case, calling the non-blocking function starts the operation and then Javascript execution continues on the next lines of Javascript.  When the non-blocking operation completes some time in the future, an event is inserted in the event queue and when the V8 engine has finished executing the current thread of execution, that event can be pulled from the event queue and a callback will get called.

You cannot write truly asynchronous operations from scratch (where actual code gets executed in the background) in pure Javascript.  You need help from an external interface (such as networking, file I/O, etc...) in order create an actual async operation.  You can simulate one with timers, but that isn't actually asynchronous because nothing actually executes in the background.  Timers just shift the timing of when things run (they don't actually do work in parallel with your Javascript execution).

Here's an example of an asynchronous operation in node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

console.log("one");
fs.readFile('temp.txt', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("got data");
    }
});
console.log("two");
```

This will generate the following output:

```
one
two
got data
```

The `fs.readFile()` operation is actually asynchronous.  After you call it, it does its work in the background while the rest of your Javascript in the statements that follow continue to execute.  When it completes, sometime in the future, it will call it's callback with either an error or the data.

Comment: I think your note on things not being "truly" asynchronous is confusing. For all intents and purposes, promises and `setTimeout` are definitely asynchronous in that they complete "at some point in the future".

Comment: @DanPantry - But, they don't execute anything in the background so all they `setTimeout()` does is shift the timing of code.  I put that in my answer to try to note that important and relevant difference.  `fs.readFile()` does real work in the background asynchronously.  `setTimeout(fn, 1000)` doesn't do any real work in the background - it just shifts the timing of when the function is called.

Comment: @toilanvd - Did this answer your question? If so, please click the green checkmark to the left of the answer to indicate that to the community and to earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

when u r calling **call.countless()** it is executing that function however there is nothing blocking I/O inside that. So Runtime is busy with doing for loop operation. If u had written any Blocking I/O operation then you would have seen the asynchronous nature of NODE JS.

e.g., Blocking I/O Operation: **File Read/Write, TimeOut, DB Operation, Ajax call**

After the for loop is complete then Interpreter goes to second function.

Comment: i think you mean non-blocking I/O. Blocking I/O would be very bad for Node.

Comment: That is where beauty lies, As the above are blocking I/O , V8 Engine will put this in Event loop, So Node single thread will be free from these blocking I/O and it will continue to execute other operation @DanPantry

Comment: Uh... no, it's not blocking I/O at all. Blocking I/O by definition is when the currently active thread will halt until the I/O operation completes. Node does not do this by default (but has the option to do so through `module.xxxxSync` operations). All standard library Node I/O functions are non-blocking unless you use these variants. V8 is not as magic as you are claiming it is.

Comment: Node JS thread is non blocking thread. But mentioned operation are blocking operation. so these operation are not executed in main single thread rather with internal thread loop

Answer (score 1):

Node in itself is not asynchronous, it just uses an event loop as a primary construct. Iterations of the event loop are executed synchronously, just like any other programming language.

Your example here does not use asynchronous code at all. Just because something is inside of a callback doesn't necessarily mean it is asynchronous (otherwise `map` would be asynchronous, for example). You're simply employing higher-order functions here.

Try putting these both inside individual `setTimeout`s; the invocation order will not be guaranteed.

Node guarantees run-to-completion (that is, any function will be wholly executed unless it `throws` until the first `return` statement), so any synchronous code will be executed in the order it is written - just like any other imperative language. Any I/O operations or things like using a `Promise` will however have their callbacks added to a task queue to be executed at some point in the future, so their execution order is not guaranteed.

Note that NodeJS is single-threaded and large `for` loops will eat up that single thread as it is a CPU bound operation, so take care when doing computationally heavy stuff like that as you will hang your entire application. For computationally heavy stuff you could yield to using a child process written in another language better suited for such a thing (using the `child_process` module).